# Relative position CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

With different div classes data showing properly in html page.Check fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/69jrvcpe/)**:

This data is showing multiple images with single div data.
Now,if there are multiple data in html with multiple images it is showing all distructed.Wants to behave it like previous fiddle.
here's the **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a37Lq5gc/)**

Div classes are:

```
div.relative {
    POSITION: relative;
    HEIGHT: 90px;
    TOP: 450px;
    LEFT: 651px;
    width: calc(100% - 651px);
    float: left;
}

div.ws14 {
    font-size: 19px;
}

div.better {
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: 603px;
    width: 410px;
    height: 280;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Why have you given `IN ALL CAPS`?

Comment: Does it effect css coding?

Comment: Nopes, but it is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to put some points here:

1. W3Schools is [terrible](http://w3fools.com/).
2. There's no `<image />` tag. It is `<img />` tag.

Your corrected code will be:

```css
div.relative {
  POSITION: relative;
  HEIGHT: 90px;
  TOP: 450px;
  LEFT: 651px;
  width: calc(100% - 651px);
  float: left;
}
div.ws14 {
  font-size: 19px;
}
div.better {
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  top: 603px;
  width: 410px;
  height: 280;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="ws14">This div element has position: relative;and this is always close and ghtgrh tfghfdgbdf tytyf tftgf</div>
</div>
<div class="ws14">This div element has position: relative;and this is always close and ghtgrh tfghfdgbdf tytyf tftgf</div>
</div>
<div class="ws14">This div element has position: relative;and this is always close and ghtgrh tfghfdgbdf tytyf tftgf</div>
</div>
<div class="ws14">This div element has position: relative;and this is always close and ghtgrh tfghfdgbdf tytyf tftgf</div>
</div>
<div class="ws14">This div element has position: relative;and this is always close and ghtgrh tfghfdgbdf tytyf tftgf</div>
</div>
<div class="better">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
</div>
```

#### Updated Snippet:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.list-img-text li {overflow: hidden; margin: 10px;}
.list-img-text img {float: left;}
.list-img-text div {float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<ul class="list-img-text">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" alt="" />
    <div>http://some-url.com/some/path</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" alt="" />
    <div>http://some-url.com/some/path</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" alt="" />
    <div>http://some-url.com/some/path</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" alt="" />
    <div>http://some-url.com/some/path</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" alt="" />
    <div>http://some-url.com/some/path</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But this is not solution i want.

Comment: @Waterflowveryhard What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want that as in 2nd fiddle most of div are in top most,they must come beside just like image showing.

Comment: You want the divs should come with one by one behind?

Comment: No just like image showing as one by one in line,same but just beside of images not of top most.

Comment: Okay... Lemme redesign for you. Do you have a pic of what you want? @Waterflowveryhard?

Comment: Yes......wait i'm creating

Comment: Here is how i want results dear,url and photos are blurred.Check http://i.imgur.com/0oPOrNG.png

Comment: @Waterflowveryhard Can you find the updated snippet please?

Comment: @Waterflowveryhard http://output.jsbin.com/vutecadoxe Check this out.

Comment: Oh dear,give me few minutes,perhaps i'have mistaken something.Your solution is good.

Comment: @Brad, sorry about my anger! `:P`